# MS Access forms are not showing JPEG pictures with a .jpeg extension

Tags: windows, forms, image, ms-access, jpeg

I have an Image Control, where the Control Source is set to the database image name column, which works fine for JPEG files with a .jpg file extension, but not working for JPEG files with a .jpeg extension. If I rename the JPEG files from .jpeg to .jpg and at the same time change the extension in the database filename from .jpeg to .jpg it works like a charm. This is not durable in a production environment, so I would really appreciate it if anyone has a workaround for this problem. I am running MS Access 2019 on a Windows 10 platform.

Comment: Unless you can do something with OLEObject control, I think you are stuck. Code can rename file and change jpeg to jpg in field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: A bash file and a crontab job running every 10 minutes. The bash file copies, transfer and rename the extensions of new files. I made an extra column in my query called "new_bill_Url_location", and stripped the "jpeg" extension and added a "jpg' extension, files with a jpg extension are left as they are. The code for the query column is:

> new_bill_Url_location: IIf(Right([bill_Url_location],4)="jpeg", Left(bill_Url_location, Len(bill_Url_location) - 4) & "jpg",[bill_Url_location])

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the simple technique demonstrated in my project [VBA.PictureUrl](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.PictureUrl). It will happily display any normal bitmap file:

[image]

This is the core function and the typical usage (in-line comments):

```vb
' Download (picture) file from a URL of a hyperlink field to a
' (temporary) folder, and return the full path to the downloaded file.
'
' This can be used as the control source for a bound picture control.
' If no Folder is specified, the user's IE cache folder is used.
'
' Typical usage in the RecordSource for a form or report where Id is
' the unique ID and Url is the hyperlink field holding the URL to
' the picture file to be displayed:
'
'   - to a cached file where parameter Id is not used:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent(0, [Url]) As Path From SomeTable;
'
'   - or, where Id is used to create the local file name:
'
'   Select *, UrlContent([Id], [Url], "d:\somefolder") As Path From SomeTable;
'
' Then, set ControlSource of the bound picture control to: Path
'
' 2017-05-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function UrlContent( _
    ByVal Id As Long, _
    ByVal Url As String, _
    Optional ByVal Folder As String) _
    As Variant

    Const NoError   As Long = 0
    Const Dot       As String = "."
    Const BackSlash As String = "\"
    
    Dim Address     As String
    Dim Ext         As String
    Dim Path        As String
    Dim Result      As String
    
    ' Strip leading and trailing octothorpes from URL string.
    Address = HyperlinkPart(Url, acAddress)
    ' If Address is a zero-length string, Url was not wrapped in octothorpes.
    If Address = "" Then
        ' Use Url as is.
        Address = Url
    End If
    
    If Folder = "" Then
        ' Import to IE cache.
        Result = DownloadCacheFile(Address)
    Else
        If Right(Folder, 1) <> BackSlash Then
            ' Append a backslash.
            Folder = Folder & BackSlash
        End If
    
        ' Retrieve extension of file name.
        Ext = StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Address), Dot)(0))
        ' Build full path for downloaded file.
        Path = Folder & CStr(Id) & Dot & Ext
        
        If DownloadFile(Address, Path) = NoError Then
            Result = Path
        End If
    End If
    
    UrlContent = Result
    
End Function
```

Comment: I don't really see how this helps with files that are on disk but have the wrong extension. Perhaps add some more explanation for that specific case?

Comment: @ErikA: The two top files listed are identical. However, the top file has been renamed to `.jpeg`. It could even had been to `.png`, and it would still display.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for the code. I tried your, but without success.

Comment: If you run Windows 11, check [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/report-an-issue/pasting-an-image-into-a-ms-access-image-ole-object-control-doesn/m-p/2975718/highlight/true#M5109) out.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for the code. I tried your code without success. I must have misunderstood something. But it led me to a solution:
I made a bash and a crontab job running every 10 minutes. The bash file copies, transfer and rename the extensions of new files.
I made an extra column in my query called [new_bill_Url_location], and stripped jpeg extension and added a jpg extension, jpg are left as they are. The code for the coloumn is:
    new_bill_Url_location: IIf(Right([bill_Url_location],4)="jpeg", Left(bill_Url_location, 
Len(bill_Url_location) - 4) & "jpg",[bill_Url_location])

Comment: @Gustav Thanks again, but I am running Windows 10.